# Criar um subdominio no wampserver

Tags: apache, wamp

Olá, preciso criar subdomínios no wampserver para poder dividir os projetos que necessitam de singularidades no .htaccess

Alguma dica?

Comment: **Opção 1 -** https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/create-virtual-hosts-in-a-wamp-server/ **Opção 2 -** http://www.axertion.com/tutorials/2012/03/how-to-setup-local-subdomains-using-wampserver/

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente na opção 1. Muito obrigado